# Are multiple databases sharding for read on docker as a good idea?

Tags: linux, virtualization, database, docker

So I have a server with multiple CPU cores and it installed a database. Do you think that if we install multiple databases (data sharding) with docker, then each request will go to different databases is a good idea? The data is different in each database and based on the request from a client it will query on the different database.

I don't know this can be worse than a dedicated database with all data or not?

Comment: its hard to predict but my guess is that it wont scale, sounds like you're trying to increase the load by installing more database managers and hoping they each use a different core when in reality that is not going to happen

Comment: yeah, basically I just want to reduce the time for clients to wait. I hope multiple database servers could run faster than 1 database server for reading.

Comment: that is true as long as they dont share the same physical resources. Perhaps this question is better suited in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would think more in terms of caching as a solution since I really dont think that installing multiple instances of the same database for sharding within a single machine will improve performance

Comment: yes, that is also I doubted, I think database server should use CPU resource effectively and adding docker with multiple database servers on 1 PC seems does not help (or even worse with reduce lot of resources).